# jquery each onclick event

Tags: jquery, onclick, each

the following code expands the comment box for a post once the slider is clicked. At the moment when the slider is clicked all the sliders in all the posts expand. How can i expand the comments box in each slider post to relate with each slider .. ( the slider,comments box has the post_id as an ID related to it )

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

            $(".comment_box").hide();


        $('.slider').on('click',function(){
            var msg = '#message';
            var postID = $(this).attr('id').replace('post_', '');
            $.ajax({
                url: 'auth/classes/comments.php',
                type: 'GET',
                data: 'post_id='+postID,
                success: function(data) {
                    $(msg).val('');
                    $(msg).css('height','14px');
                    $('.commentscontainer_'+postID).append(data);
                    $('.time').timeago();
                }
            });
        $(".comment_box").slideToggle();
        });

    });
```

HTML is like this ( was inside a loop so )

```
<div class="slider" id="post_['post_id']">&nbsp;</div></span></span>
<div class="comment_box" 'id="['post_id']">'
<div class="commentscontainer_['post_id']">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: You mean u only want one post to be expanded at a time right?

Comment: It's impossible to answer without knowing how `.slider` relates to `.comment_box` in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

In this line you add the comment in the box you want to expand:

```
$('.commentscontainer_'+postID).append(data);
```

If I'm right, the "comment_box" is a container of the '.commentscontainer_XX".

So, you can select the closest parent with "comment_box" class name using

```
$('.commentscontainer_'+postID).append(data).closest(".comment_box").slideDown();
```

Instead of the $(".comment_box").slideToggle() that you have at the end of your function.

The whole function became:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

            $(".comment_box").hide();


        $('.slider').on('click',function(){
            var msg = '#message';
            var postID = $(this).attr('id').replace('post_', '');
            $.ajax({
                url: 'auth/classes/comments.php',
                type: 'GET',
                data: 'post_id='+postID,
                success: function(data) {
                    $(msg).val('');
                    $(msg).css('height','14px');
                    $('.commentscontainer_'+postID).append(data).closest(".comment_box").slideDown();
                    $('.time').timeago();
                }
            });
        });

    });
```

Comment: Its just that once the slider is clicked all the comments boxes expands in all posts.. not just on the one i clicked don

Comment: @user2668436 the idea of using closest is to refer just one .comment_box, the one that contains the new post added with ajax.

Answer (score 0):

each `.comment_box` has the ID `['post_id']`, that you already have in a variable :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".comment_box").hide();

    $('.slider').on('click',function(){
        var postID = this.id.replace('post_', '');
        $.ajax({
            url : 'auth/classes/comments.php',
            data: {post_id: postID}
        }).done(function(data) {
            $('#message').val('').css('height','14px');
            $('.commentscontainer_'+postID).append(data);
            $('.time').timeago();
        });
        $('#' + postID).slideToggle();
    });
});
```

**EDIT:**

To only do the ajax call on sliding down, you'd either have to wait for the callback and check if the element is visible, or you could use a flag, like so :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".comment_box").hide();

    $('.slider').on('click',function(){
        var flag   = $(this).data('flag'),
            postID = this.id.replace('post_', '');

        $('#' + postID).slideToggle();

        if (!flag) {
            $.ajax({
                url : 'auth/classes/comments.php',
                data: {post_id: postID}
            }).done(function(data) {
                $('#message').val('').css('height','14px');
                $('.commentscontainer_'+postID).append(data);
                $('.time').timeago();
            });
        }
        $(this).data('flag', !flag)
    });
});
```

Comment: WORKED !! THANKS ALOT ~~

Comment: Can i send the ajax request only when the comments box is shown when slider is clicked ? ( at the moment it sends ajaxes on show and hide ) ?

Comment: @user2668436 - sure, added that as well!

Comment: YOU ARE A GOD !! ( dont know if im pushing it or not.. is there a way to replace the whole comments box for each ajax with out appending it?)

Comment: used replaceWith.. Thanks anyways.. :)